# How to fetch data from nested JSON response and pass to next request in postman?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have a JSON response as below.

```
{
    "SearchId": "AD9AD002JKLNLSF7",
    "TanxId": "789456g78udk9",
    "Test": [{
        "Outgoing": [{
            "Identifier": null,
            "AirId": "eff4f689-8b49",
            "Fare": "a0b8ac00-e6ab"
        }]
    }]
}
```

How can I get value of "AirId" and "Fare" from this response and pass to next request?

I tried below but it's not working.

```
var FareId = jsonData.Test[0].Outgoing.Fare;
pm.globals.set(“Fareref”, FareId);
```

Comment: `Outgoing` is an array.

Comment: Yes it is an array

Comment: Yup, I was implying that you cannot access it using `Outgoing.Fare`, you need `Outgoing[0].Fare`.

Comment: I tried Outgoing[0].Fare also but getting below error:                                                                                                                                      "There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: That seems like a different syntax error in your script. Can you paste the whole script in the question?

Comment: {
  "SearchId": "jds8addd734",
  "TranxId": "nhdsjlkf342fk3kj",
  "Test": [
    {
      "Outgoing": [
        {
          "Identifier": "null",
          "AirId": "eff4f689-8b49",
          "Fare": "a0b8ac00-e6ab",
          "FltId": 0
        }
      ],
      "FareDtl": {
        "BuyingPrice": 0,
        "TotalPrice": 0,
        "Fare": "a0b8ac00-e6ab",
        
      }
    }
  ],
  "TraxId": "hj7ds23kj9",
  "ExecTime": 0
}

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and not sure how can I paste the JSON response in JSON view format.

Comment: Below solution is working for my question, thanks all for your help.

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var FareId = jsonData. Test[0].Outgoing[0].Fare;
pm.globals.set("Fareref", FareId);

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, please select the solution below as the official answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
var oJson = JSON.parse('{ "SearchId": "AD9AD002JKLNLSF7", "TanxId": "789456g78udk9", "Test": [{ "Outgoing": [{ "Identifier": null, "AirId": "eff4f689-8b49", "Fare": "a0b8ac00-e6ab" }] }] }');

console.log(oJson.Test[0].Outgoing[0].AirId);
console.log(oJson.Test[0].Outgoing[0].Fare);
```

Comment: And how can I call it in next requests? Actually I am looking for a solution where I can set it as a global variable and call in next requests.